# Parsing DNS response Answer section doesn't give expected results

Tags: java, dns

I'm trying to parse a DNS response using java. I'm following [RFC-1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) for guidelines on how to send requests and receieve responses, the format that is.

According to said RFC the answer section of a response should look like so:

```
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                                               |
/                                               /
/                      NAME                     /
|                                               |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                      TYPE                     |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                     CLASS                     |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                      TTL                      |
|                                               |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                   RDLENGTH                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--|
/                     RDATA                     /
/                                               /
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

I'm trying to parse the `NAME` section.

According to section 4.1.4. Message compression I should be able to get the first 2 bits and determine if the next byte is either a label or a pointer.

Here's my code so far, the request works just fine for a `A` record of `google.com` using CouldFlare as a DNS

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Random;

public class Stuff {
    private static final String DNS_SERVER_ADDRESS = "1.1.1.1";
    private static final int DNS_SERVER_PORT = 53;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String domain = "google.com";
        InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(DNS_SERVER_ADDRESS);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
        //Whenever an octet represents a numeric quantity, the left most bit in
        //the diagram is the high order or most significant bit.
        //this goes for requests as well as responses


       short requestFlags = Short.parseShort("0000000100000000", 2);
        ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort(requestFlags);
        byte[] array = bytes.array();
        dos.writeShort(1234); // randomly chosen id
        dos.write(array);
        dos.writeShort(1); // QDCOUNT
        dos.writeShort(0); // ANCOUNT
        dos.writeShort(0); // NSCOUNT
        dos.writeShort(0); // ARCOUNT

        String[] domainParts = domain.split("\\.");
        System.out.println(domain + " has " + domainParts.length + " parts");

        for (int i = 0; i < domainParts.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Writing: " + domainParts[i]);
            byte[] domainBytes = domainParts[i].getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            dos.writeByte(domainBytes.length);
            dos.write(domainBytes);
        }

        // No more parts
        dos.writeByte(0);
        // Type 0x01 = A (Host Request)
        dos.writeShort(1);
        // Class 0x01 = IN
        dos.writeShort(1);

        byte[] dnsFrame = baos.toByteArray();

        System.out.println("Sending: " + dnsFrame.length + " bytes");
        for (int i = 0; i < dnsFrame.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(String.format("%s", dnsFrame[i]) + " ");
        }

        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
        DatagramPacket dnsReqPacket = new DatagramPacket(dnsFrame, dnsFrame.length, ipAddress, DNS_SERVER_PORT);
        socket.send(dnsReqPacket);

        // Await response from DNS server
        byte[] buf = new byte[512];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        socket.receive(packet);

        System.out.println("\n\nReceived: " + packet.getLength() + " bytes");

        for (int i = 0; i < packet.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.print(String.format("%s", buf[i]) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        //All communications inside of the domain protocol are carried in a single
        //format called a message.  The top level format of message is divided
        //into 5 sections (some of which are empty in certain cases) shown below:
        //    +---------------------+
        //    |        Header       |
        //    +---------------------+
        //    |       Question      | the question for the name server
        //    +---------------------+
        //    |        Answer       | RRs answering the question
        //    +---------------------+
        //    |      Authority      | RRs pointing toward an authority
        //    +---------------------+
        //    |      Additional     | RRs holding additional information
        //    +---------------------+

        // HEADER
        //                                    1  1  1  1  1  1
        //      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5
        //    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
        //    |                      ID                       |
        //    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
        //    |QR|   Opcode  |AA|TC|RD|RA|   Z    |   RCODE   |
        //    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
        //    |                    QDCOUNT                    |
        //    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
        //    |                    ANCOUNT                    |
        //    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
        //    |                    NSCOUNT                    |
        //    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
        //    |                    ARCOUNT                    |
        //    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+

        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buf));
        System.out.println("\n\nStart response decode");
        System.out.println("Transaction ID: " + din.readShort()); // ID
        short flags = din.readByte();
        int QR = (flags & 0b10000000) >>> 7; //QR
        int opCode = ( flags & 0b01111000) >>> 3; //Opcode
        int AA = ( flags & 0b00000100) >>> 2; //AA
        int TC = ( flags & 0b00000010) >>> 1; //TC
        int RD =  flags & 0b00000001;//RD
        System.out.println("QR "+QR);
        System.out.println("Opcode "+opCode);
        System.out.println("AA "+AA);
        System.out.println("TC "+TC);
        System.out.println("RD "+RD);
        flags = din.readByte();
        int RA = (flags & 0b10000000) >>> 7;//RA
        int Z = ( flags & 0b01110000) >>> 4;//Z
        int RCODE =  flags & 0b00001111;//RCODE
        System.out.println("RA "+RA);
        System.out.println("Z "+ Z);
        System.out.println("RCODE " +RCODE);

        System.out.println("Questions: " + String.format("%s", din.readShort())); //QDCOUNT
        System.out.println("Answers RRs: " + String.format("%s", din.readShort())); //ANCOUNT
        System.out.println("Authority RRs: " + String.format("%s", din.readShort())); //NSCOUNT
        System.out.println("Additional RRs: " + String.format("%s", din.readShort())); //ARCOUNT

        // Question
        //      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5
        //    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
        //    |                                               |
        //    /                     QNAME                     /
        //    /                                               /
        //    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
        //    |                     QTYPE                     |
        //    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
        //    |                     QCLASS                    |
        //    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
        int recLen;
        while ((recLen = din.readByte()) > 0) {
            byte[] record = new byte[recLen];
            for (int i = 0; i < recLen; i++) {
                record[i] = din.readByte();
            }
            System.out.println("Record: " + new String(record, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); //QNAME
        }
        System.out.println("Record Type: " + String.format("%s", din.readShort()));//QTYPE
        System.out.println("QCLASS - Class: " + String.format("%s", din.readShort())); // QCLASS
        System.out.println("\n\nstart answer, authority, and additional sections\n");

        //The answer, authority, and additional
        //      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5
        //    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
        //    |                                               |
        //    /                                               /
        //    /                      NAME                     /
        //    |                                               |
        //    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
        //    |                      TYPE                     |
        //    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
        //    |                     CLASS                     |
        //    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
        //    |                      TTL                      |
        //    |                                               |
        //    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
        //    |                   RDLENGTH                    |
        //    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--|
        //    /                     RDATA                     /
        //    /                                               /
        //    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
        byte firstBytes = din.readByte();
        int firstTwoBits = (firstBytes & 0b11000000) >>> 6;
        //    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
        //    | 1  1|                OFFSET                   |
        //    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
        // 11 for offset
        //(The 10 and 01 combinations
        //are reserved for future use.)
        // 00 for label
        //label must begin with two zero bits because
        //labels are restricted to 63 octets or less
        System.out.println(firstTwoBits);
        if(firstTwoBits == 3) {
            System.out.println("It's a pointer");
        }else if(firstTwoBits == 0){
            System.out.println("It's a label");
        }

    }
}
```

And the printed info

```
google.com has 2 parts
Writing: google
Writing: com
Sending: 28 bytes
4 -46 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 103 111 111 103 108 101 3 99 111 109 0 0 1 0 1 

Received: 44 bytes
4 -46 -127 -128 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 6 103 111 111 103 108 101 3 99 111 109 0 0 1 0 1 -64 12 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 27 0 4 -114 -5 37 110 



Start response decode
Transaction ID: 1234
QR 1
Opcode 0
AA 0
TC 0
RD 1
RA 1
Z 0
RCODE 0
Questions: 1
Answers RRs: 1
Authority RRs: 0
Additional RRs: 0
Record: google
Record: com
Record Type: 1
QCLASS - Class: 1


start answer, authority, and additional sections

3
It's a pointer

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comparing this with a command line DNS lookup tool

```
id 1329, opcode QUERY, rcode NOERROR, flags QR RD RA
;QUESTION
google.com. IN A
;ANSWER
google.com. 257 IN A 142.250.81.206
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL
```

The result I get seems valid.

My problem is that I can't seem to parse the `NAME` in the answer section. It seems to start with a pointer which makes no sense.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong here but I can't tell what.

I understand that what I'm asking is vague but then again if I knew what the issue was I wouldn't be here.

I've also used Wireshark to incercept a request I did to make sure the response is correct. It seems to be correct indeed(I've obviously changed the url to stackoverflow.com)

[image]

Comment: *My problem is that I can't seem to parse the NAME in the answer section. It seems to start with a pointer which makes no sense.* I probably know at lot less about this than you but am wondering why you say that? `firstByte` is telling you there's a pointer and the following value (0x0c) shows you the offset of the name for compression purposes (if I've got that right)

Comment: Actually...you're correct. I wrongly assumed that a name can't start with an offset since it would make no sense for it to do that and the example used in the RFC didn't start with a pointer. Clearly I was wrong. If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: The RFC is has example of name compression, see §4.1.4 of RFC 1035 with a packet using compression and full explanation. Also, if it is to learn then it is ok, but otherwise DO NOT attempt to write a DNS library, reuse any good one existing in your programming language. DNS is far from being easy. Your code makes a lot of assumptions that would work in a controlled environment but if you put that in production on the wild Internet you will get exposed to all sorts of unexpected/bad DNS content that will make your code explode (there are exploits using bad implementation regarding pointers)

Comment: One example: you expect a reply to fit a 512 bytes buffer. You can't be sure of that, you can get more data than that, and if you try to parse only the first 512 bytes you might get truncated data that won't work in your code.

Comment: "My problem is that I can't seem to parse the NAME in the answer section. It seems to start with a pointer which makes no sense." In completely makes sense here, because the name in the answer will be (should be) exactly the same in the question, hence the answer part will use compression and point to the name in the question part to avoid duplicating it.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek 2.3.4. Size limits: UDP messages 512 octets or less. As far as writing my own DNS server...it's good practice and also fun.

Comment: @AndreiP. Did you see when the RFC was written? Understanding the DNS is not possible by reading just one documentation and we certainly shouldn't start this discussion as comments there but maybe look at https://indico.dns-oarc.net/event/27/contributions/469/attachments/449/749/2017-09-29-xtn-hdrs-dns.pdf or https://indico.dns-oarc.net/event/36/contributions/776/attachments/754/1277/DefragDNS-Axel_Koolhaas-Tjeerd_Slokker.pdf and https://ednscomp.isc.org/ednscomp. Plus, you seem to forget that DNS is over both UDP AND TCP, an error often made. See the sense of the TC flag for starter.

Comment: "As far as writing my own DNS server...it's good practice and also fun." Yes, certainly a good exercise to learn various things. But absolutely not to put in production on the wild Internet.

Comment: "2.3.4. Size limits: UDP messages 512 octets or less.". Do a `TXT` query on `google.com` and see the size... Things can be even worse in case of DNSSEC due to the added `RRSIG` records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that I can't seem to parse the NAME in the answer
> section. It seems to start with a pointer which makes no sense.

I probably know at lot less about this than you but am wondering why you say that? `firstByte` is telling you there's a pointer and the following value (0x0c) shows you the offset of the name for compression purposes (if I've got that right). None of the other bits in the same byte as `firstByte` is set so that can be ignored from the point of view of the offset value

Comment: "and the following value (0x0c) shows you the offset of the name for compression purposes " That is incorrect. it is not "one byte to tell it is a pointer, and then another byte to tell the offset", see §4.1.4 of RFC 1035. You have to take into account 16 bits (2 bytes). If they start by `11` then **ALL** the following bits (hence 14 of them spanning 2 bytes) are the value of the offset. So you need to take into account both bytes, but just removing the two leading bits with value `1` to get to the offset.

Comment: *You have to take into account 16 bits (...* You need to read my answer more carefully

Comment: Or maybe you need to improve your answer (you say yourself "if I've got that right") to be both clearer and citing sources (see my comments for the relevant RFC and section), which was the aim of my comment, helping you write a better answer and have at the same time a better understanding of what you are trying to explain.

Comment: The sources are already cited. I'm sorry but there is nothing in my answer that is "incorrect" and I don't appreciate people stating that, *plus* implying that I asserted things that I didn't. Again, you need to read what I stated more carefully

Comment: Then reread what you wrote: "None of the other bits in the same byte as firstByte is set so that can be ignored from the point of view of the offset value" This is INCORRECT. The last 6 bits of `firstByte` are part of the offset. That can not be ignored as you state. The offset value is composed of the last 6 bits of `firstByte` plus the whole `secondByte` so to say. And there are no references in your answer at all, while the relevant one as already stated elsewhere is RFC 1035 §4.1.4, maybe read it to understand what is incorrect in what you wrote?

Comment: *"None of the other bits in the same byte as firstByte is set so that can be ignored from the point of view of the offset value" This is INCORRECT. The last 6 bits of firstByte are part of the offset.* 
Please explain how six (leading) zeroed bits are significant to the offset

Comment: "Please explain how six (leading) zeroed bits are significant to the offset". Simple (if you read the reference): there is no reason it will ALWAYS be 6 times zero. Maybe it is on this example, and maybe it won't be on another case. If you write a DNS parser you can't know in advance what you will get so you will have to stick to what the references say and use the offset properly, which is 14 bits without assumption in advance if you have zeros or not. This is called reading the specifications and not interpreting things. So, AGAIN, the last 6 bits of `firstByte` ARE significant in general.

Comment: *Simple (if you read the reference): there is no reason it will ALWAYS be 6 times zero.* You haven't answered the *specific* question I put to you and again, you're implying I have stated things which I have *not*. I was talking about a *particular case*. Were I writing a Java DNS API (which I wouldn't as it would probably be reinventing the wheel) I would obviously check if the value was exactly `0b11000000` (which it probably *would* be in most cases) as bit-shifting for the pointer value would be a waste of time

Comment: " I would obviously check if the value was exactly 0b1100000" You still don't understand and probably haven't read the reference given that explain what you have to do so at this point it is useless for me to repeat things all over. Again, you must not check for this literal value at all, just the first 2 bits being 1. Otherwise you are just implementing a faulty DNS parser not handling name compression right, but you wouldn't be the first one unfortunately, there is/was a ton of software exhibiting the kind of errors you are perpetuating here.